# Jump if overflow (Assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, overflow, att

In this code I'm trying to print 1 if the 32bits integer overflows and 0 if not.
But I keep getting 0 either it overflows or not. Here's my code with an example which should overflow and print 1. Any help is appreciated.

```
    .section .data
    x:
        .int 4100000000          
    y:
        .int 400000000

.section .text
.global _start

_start:

    movl y, %eax            #moves the value y to %eax
    addl x, %eax            #adds the value x to %eax

    jo output_with_overflow #jump if overflow

    movl $0, %eax
    jmp end

output_with_overflow:
    movl $1, %eax
    jmp end

end:

    movl %eax, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

Comment: Your given code doesn't attempt to print anything. How are you printing the output?

Comment: @GregHewgill looks like it's using the exit code of the program

Comment: Yes, that much is clear, but the problem might be in the code that handles the exit code and prints the result. The OP says the code as given prints 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the overflow flag is for signed arithmetic. Your operands, when considered signed, will not overflow because `4100000000` is `-194967296` and adding `400000000` does not overflow. If you want unsigned overflow, test the carry flag. If you want signed overflow, use a different number, near the maximum signed number on 32 bits, which is `2^31-1=2147483647`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a linux `sys_exit` syscall with `eax=1` and `ebx=<exit code>`...

Your program checks for overflow flag, but for unsigned values should check for carry.

I have also simplified it a little bit to avoid not neccessary moves around - you may prepare exit code in `ebx` just after the check.

```
    .section .data
    x:
        .int 4100000000
    y:
        .int 400000000

.section .text
.global _start

_start:
    movl y, %eax #moves the value y to %eax
    addl x, %eax #adds the value x to %eax

    jc output_with_overflow #jump if carry

    movl $0, %ebx
    jmp end

output_with_overflow:
    movl $1, %ebx
    jmp end

end:
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

There is a trick when the result is in the carry flag:

```
_start:
    movl $0, %ebx
    movl y, %eax #moves the value y to %eax
    addl x, %eax #adds the value x to %eax
    adcl $0, %ebx

    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```